# PHP class instantiation multiple times

Tags: php, oop

Will having multiple instances of same class affects loading time?I want to use class methods in two different templates and later combine both the templates using include().
For example:
**First.php**

```
<?php
    $object_first = new Class();
    print_r($object_first->SomeMethod());
?>
```

**Second.php**

```
<?php
    $object_second = new Class();
    print_r($object_second->DifferentMethod());
?>
```

**Combined.php**

```
<?php
    include('first.php');
    include('second.php');
?>
```

I know i can create object once is combined.php and just use that object in both the templates , but to keep it simple and clear i want to do it other way.
So my question is  will be there any performance issues if i create multiple objects?

Comment: It depends on what object methods will do

Comment: methods are database queries

Comment: yhea creating multiple objects will consume memory, you can just check object created already and if just call method or use static methods or other way. avoid creating multiple objects

Comment: "methods are database queries" - i guess your class creates connection to database each time you create new instance of it. So in this situation better to use it inside combined.php